# Structuring Java submit payment in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, braintree

I am using Braintree's java library within Coldfusion 10. I am running into an issue when I actually try to submit a payment. How would I write this line of code in CF, assuming all of the values I am passing in are the same name.

```
Result<Transaction> result = gateway.transaction().sale(transactionRequest);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I am running into an issue* What is the issue? Are you getting an error? If so, update your question to include a) your current code and b) the error message - including the stack trace. Also, can you include a link to the API you are using?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but if you are struggling with the [java generics syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), just ignore it. CF being weakly typed, it does not apply. Assuming you already created the `gateway` and `transactionRequest` objects, just invoke the method as usual: `result = gateway.transaction().sale(transactionRequest);`. That is all I can suggest without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a [cfpayment project](https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment) with a CFC built that you can use.  Check out [this](https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment/tree/master/api/gateway/braintree), looks like it has all the necessary functionality.